# Filter specific values from array of string

Tags: swift

I have an array of following values

```
["130896-220","130897-901","130011-990","130012-991"]
```

and I am filter out of only those values which contain 900 to 999 at end of value.

I need following result of array `["130897-901","130011-990","130012-991"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call **`filter(_:)`** on `arr` with the relevant condition to filter the elements within the range `900...999`

```
let arr =  ["130896-220","130897-901","130011-990","130012-991"]
let range = (900...999)
let result = arr.filter({
    if let str = $0.components(separatedBy: "-").last, let num = Int(str) {
        return range.contains(num)
    }
    return false
})
print(result) //["130897-901", "130011-990", "130012-991"]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is Regular Expression

```
let array = ["130896-220","130897-901","130011-990","130012-991"]
let filteredArray = array.filter{$0.range(of: "^\\d{6}-9\\d{2}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil}
```

The pattern `"^\\d{6}-9\\d{2}$"` searches for

- six digits followed by
- one hyphen followed by
- `9` followed by
- two other digits

Answer (score 0):

A little bit unconventional Objective-C solution:

```
NSArray *data = @[@"130896-220", @"130896-901", @"130896-903"];

// We'll fill this array with the final filtered result
NSMutableArray* filteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString* str in data) { // Iterate between strings
    int value = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"][1] intValue];
    if(value > 900 && value < 1000){
        [filteredData addObject:str];
    }
}
```

Edit:
Inside the for I use the method `componentsSeparatedByString:@""` this will return an array with strings separated by the entered value. In this case we know that we want the value after the "-" character so we access the second index of the array directly ([1]).
Lastly, we check if the value is compressed between the values we want. If so, is added to the filtered array.

Comment: Could you add some detail as to what your answer is doing?